# Discord to twitter python bot gives error about requests?

Tags: python, discord.py

I got this error below after running my code that looks for messages in a Discord channel, and if it has an image it sends that image.

Anyone knows why and what I can do to fix it?

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/discord-to-twitter/main.py", line 79, in <module>
    client.run(
  File "/home/runner/discord-to-twitter/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 828, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "/nix/store/7c2d4f13a93vf8xx548czn0v0hsgrrkv-python3-3.10.0/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/nix/store/7c2d4f13a93vf8xx548czn0v0hsgrrkv-python3-3.10.0/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 641, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/runner/discord-to-twitter/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 817, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "/home/runner/discord-to-twitter/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 745, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "/home/runner/discord-to-twitter/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 580, in login
    data = await self.http.static_login(token)
  File "/home/runner/discord-to-twitter/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 801, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/home/runner/discord-to-twitter/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 680, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 429 Too Many Requests (error code: 0)
```

```py
import discord
import tweepy
import requests
import imghdr
from PIL import Image
import shutil
import urllib
import os
from keep_alive import keep_alive

client2 = tweepy.Client(
    bearer_token=
    'my_token',
    consumer_key='my_token',
    consumer_secret='my_token',
    access_token='my_token',
    access_token_secret='my_token')

auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
    'my_token',
    'my_token',
    'my_token',
    'my_token')

# Create the API object using the OAuth1 user handler
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Create the discord client with the default intents
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # check if the message is in a server (not a DM) and not from the bot itself
    if message.guild and message.author != client.user:
        # get the channel object for the channel you want to monitor
        channel = client.get_channel(973613949935317023)
        # check if the message was sent in the specified channel
        if message.channel == channel:
            # get the list of attachments for the message
            attachments = message.attachments
            content = message.content
            author = message.author
            # check if the message has any attachments
            if attachments:
                # loop over the attachments
                for attachment in attachments:
                    # get the URL of the attachment
                    image_url = attachment.url

                    img = Image.open(requests.get(image_url, stream=True).raw)

                    if not os.path.exists('photo.png'):
                        # create the file if it doesn't exist
                        open('photo.png', 'a').close()

                    img.save('photo.png')
                    filename = 'photo.png'

                    # upload the file
                    media = api.media_upload(filename)
                    print(filename)
                    client2.create_tweet(
                        text=
                        ' {author} JUST made this at @leveragedevils! Join while you still can! We would love to have you!                      #btc #eth #solnfts #crypto #stocks #money #levdevtrading #sol #nft',
                        media_ids=[media.media_id])

                # add a reaction to the user's message
                await message.add_reaction('✅')

                # respond to the user's message with "Tweeted!"
                await message.channel.send('Tweeted!')
                os.remove('photo.png')

keep_alive()
client.run("my_token")
```

I tried to search on the internet but didn't find any solutions. I think it sends too many requests but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: [replit](https://ask.replit.com/t/discord-ratelimit/3522) isn't the best solution for hosting a bot. You get rate limited due the fact that the IP is shared and other bots are making requests to the discord API

Comment: I have some confusing because if `message.channel` is a different instance to `channel`, for example **client.get_channel** is of a Thread instance then it **message.channel** should not have a propper comparission operator, as each one are described in documentation having uniquely comparission operators description not for different types idk what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

To integrate a cooroutine is recommended to check methods from [Wait Primitives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) that waits until a certain task is performed. When generating too much requests an `exception` is raised when timeout is greater than limit, optionally it could be determined as a **float** value `discord.Client(intents=intents, max_ratelimit_timeout=30.0)`.

```
client.wait_until_ready()
while not client.is_closed() and message.guild and message.author != client.user:
    channel = client.get_channel(ID)
    if message.channel == channel: pass
        # await asyncio.sleep(100) you could try asyncio.sleep
    channel.close()
```

Comment: Hii man, thanks for the answer,

Sadly I don't know how to implement this into my code, can you help me some more with that?

Comment: change conditional statement `if message.guild and message.author != client.user` by `while not client.is_closed() and message.guild and message.author != client.user`, **sleep** method could help if you have a file that take too long to load.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is executed without errors.

bot permissions (*MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT* allowed)
[image: discord permissions]

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.guild and message.author != client.user:
        channel = client.get_channel(ID)
        if message.channel == channel:
            attachments = message.attachments
            content = message.content
            author = message.author
            print(author, content, attachments)
            if attachments:
                for attachment in attachments:
                    image_url = attachment.url 
                    img = Image.open(requests.get(image_url, stream=True).raw) 
                    if not os.path.exists('photo.png'):
                        open('photo.png', 'a').close() 
                    img.save('photo.png')
                    filename = 'photo.png' 
                    await message.channel.send(await attachment.to_file())
                    file = discord.File(filename)
                    await message.channel.send(file=file, content="Message to be sent")
                await message.add_reaction('✅')
                await message.channel.send('Forwarded')
```

CMD output

```
[2022-12-22 12:14:06] [INFO] discord.client: logging in using static token
[2022-12-22 12:14:07] [INFO] discord.gateway: Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID).
logged in as bot#
[<Attachment id=idfilename='image.png' url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/image.png'>]
photo.png
```

the above example shows that is possibly to [download and upload files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/junw7.png), I just have take a screenshot on the channel and send it again from bot, what means that you have not established correctly discord permissions or maybe you need to wrap **tweepy** asynchronously.

```py
import asyncio
import functools

import tweepy  # type: ignore
from tweepy import * 

async def acall(f, *args, **kwargs):
    return await asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor(
        None, lambda: f(*args, **kwargs)
    )


def awrap(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return await acall(f, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper 

def create_aproxy_class(cls):
    class AsyncProxy:
        __name__ = cls.__name__
        __doc__ = cls.__doc__

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.proxy = cls(*args, **kwargs)

        def __getattr__(self, attr):
            attr = getattr(self.proxy, attr)
            return awrap(attr) if callable(attr) else attr

    return AsyncProxy


API = create_aproxy_class(tweepy.API)
```

define api

```py
import atweepy

async def upload(key, secret, access_token, access_token_secret):
    try:
        auth = atweepy.OAuthHandler(key, secret)
    except tweepy.TweepError:
        return
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = atweepy.API(
        auth,
        retry_count=3,
        retry_delay=10,
        wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True,
        wait_on_rate_limit=True,
        compression=True,
    )
    return api
```

you need to implement this to the bot

```
        if attachments:
            for attachment in attachments:
                image_url = attachment.url 
                img = Image.open(requests.get(image_url, stream=True).raw) 
                if not os.path.exists('photo.png'):
                    open('photo.png', 'a').close() 
                img.save('photo.png')
                filename = 'photo.png'
                # tweepy api
                media = await api.media_upload(filename)
                client2.create_tweet(text='text', media_ids=[media.media_id])
```